# How to Dockerfile FROM another Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an application that has two `Dockerfile`, say `Dockerfile.foo` and `Dockerfile.bar`, which are expected to produce two different images for two different services of `docker-compose.yml`.

For example, it may looks like:

```
# ...
services:
  service1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.foo
  service1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.bar
# ...
```

But both `Dockerfile.{foo,bar}` share the same first half while their left parts differ.

How to avoid unnecessary duplicate builds and maintenance hassle by making `.{foo,bar}` extend from a base `Dockerfile.common`? In other words, is it possible to archive something like `FROM Dockerfile.common` within `docker-compose.yml`?

---

Update:

What I expect is using `docker-compose` to automate the build process without manually (or with a separate `build.sh`) running:

1. `docker build -f Dockerfile.common -t common .` at first;
2. and then `docker build -f Dockerfile.foo -t foo . && docker build -f Dockerfile.bar -t bar .` so that `Dockerfile.{foo, bar}` can properly refer to the `common` image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714123/docker-compose-cascade-build-images is a very similar question (my answer there talks a little more about the workflow).

Comment: Create a docker file for base images that are common for both the projects. Trim the remaining two docker files for specifc builds and add all three to docker-compose.yml

Comment: @iSahilSharma Sorry I did not make my question clear. It is the question per se. I have updated it.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks a lot. That question is very similar to mine although it is slightly different. I think the answer you give in that problem just targets at my question. But I am still wondering whether there are other more elegant solutions that only requires `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to avoid playing around with unnecessary intermediate tags and you use Docker 20.10+, you can also do this:

```
# syntax = edrevo/dockerfile-plus

INCLUDE+ Dockerfile.common

# The rest of Dockerfile.foo would go after the INCLUDE+ instruction

RUN echo "Hello World"
```

The `INCLUDE+` instruction gets imported by the first line in the Dockerfile. You can read more about the dockerfile-plus at https://github.com/edrevo/dockerfile-plus

Comment: If you were already using an extended syntax like the official `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.4`, I know no way to use both.

Answer (score 5):

I only dabble with Docker every now and then, so I'm not sure of whether there's a better and more Docker-ish way to do this, but I use a good old makefile.

***makefile***

```
common:
    docker build -f Dockerfile.common -t common .

foo: common
    docker build -f Dockerfile.foo -t foo .

bar: common
    docker build -f Dockerfile.bar -t bar .

build: foo bar
    echo "Done!"
```

Then run:

```
make build
```

I don't know whether Docker Compose can do this too in a better and more elegant way, but this worked for me, without having to learn and install a new tool ;)

Comment: Nope, docker-compose is just for orchestration (in some way), so you can use it to run containers simultaniously. That is not what you want here. Anyway, I like the makfefile-way you suggested!

Answer (score -1):

`FROM` serves to pull a base image to work with. Of course, that image has a `Dockerfile` somewhere, but that does not matter within the new `Dockerfile` that uses that image.

So, create a main `Dockerfile_common` and generate an image `generated_image_with_Dockerfile_common` from there (with `docker build`), with the basic stuff you'll need in your other images.

Then, in your `Dockerfile_foo` and `Dockerfile_bar`, use `FROM generated_image_with_Dockerfile_common` and complete them with what you want.

Comment: Have you read the question? this is exactly the unwanted scenario that a solution is required for